Mistake in fill between picture
I write the following code
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xtick=\empty,
        ]
        \addplot[name path=K,blue,domain={-1.5:1.5},samples=300] {x^5};
        \addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-1.5:1.5},samples=500] {x};   
    \addplot [gray] fill between [of=K and F];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

and the picture I get is for sure wrong, since the line I see is not $y=x$ and I cannot find the mistake.

Note that most of the time it's not a good idea to show a plot without any ticks (only if you want to show some qualitative behaviour this is fine).

The line F is indeed x = y, the two axis are just with a different scale, if you added ticks you'd see that.
This is your plot with the two lines xtick=\empty, and ytick=\empty, removed:

If you want the plot F to be at 45° you'd have to make sure that both axes are scaled identically, you could achieve that using xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax (probably there's a better solution):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin = -5,
        xmax = 5,
        ymin = -5,
        ymax = 5,
        ytick=\empty,
        xtick=\empty,
        ]
        \addplot[name path=K,blue,domain={-1.5:1.5},samples=300] {x^5};
        \addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-1.5:1.5},samples=500] {x};   
    \addplot [gray] fill between [of=K and F];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


